# D3 select on ID parentNode

Tags: javascript, d3.js

If my HTML is

```
<html>
<script src="d3.min.js" type="text/JavaScript"></script>
 <body>
   <div id="borderdiv">meh</div>
 </body>
 <script type="text/JavaScript">console.log((d3.select("#borderdiv")[0]));</script>
</html>
```

and I `d3.select("#borderdiv")`, should the result have parentNode as `body` or `html`?  I'd expect the former but get the latter.

Please note that in practice I do not actually want the parentNode: rather this is a minimal case of a behavior that I find unexpected.  I want to know if it's a bug in d3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [d3.js selections](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#d3_select), each selection is an *array of arrays* of elements, where the sub-arrays

> have additional methods [bound] to the array so that you can apply operators to the selected elements.

Thus `d3.select("#borderdiv")[0]` is an *array* (with `parentNode` set by d3.js to the DOM root), not a node itself.

What you want is

`d3.select("#borderdiv")[0][0].parentNode`.

EDIT:

From [the docs](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#subselections):

> Grouping by selectAll also affects subsequent entering placeholder nodes. Thus, to specify the parent node when appending entering nodes, use `select` followed by `selectAll`:

```
d3.select("#borderdiv")
  .selectAll("#borderdiv")
  .data("ipsum dolor sit amet".split(" "))
  .enter()
  .append("div");
```

Comment: Thanks kindly. The code above was actually minimized to try to understand behavior. What I really want to do is set data() and then enter().append() nodes but, depending on how I do the select, the appended nodes end up after the body rather than after the div. I was wondering if this is bug or a feature. E.g. chaning the script to 

    `<script type="text/JavaScript">d3.select("#borderdiv").data("ipsum dolor sit amet".split(" ")).enter().append("div");</script>`

Comment: I edited the original post.  Thanks again for the answer.

Comment: Safe to say it's not a bug, it's a function of the return value of a d3 `select` statement. See my edit above for an example of how to specify the parent node when appending.

Answer (score 1):

Actually a better way is to nevermind d3 here. It's much simpler and cleaner if you just write it in plain javascript:

```
document.getElementById('borderdiv').parentNode();
```

Answer (score 1):

interesting question, Let me share my answer.

If you are really interested in the immediate parent node (In your case `body`) here is a hustle free way to get it.

```
var parent = d3.select("#borderdiv").select(function(){
   return this.parentNode;
})
```

I am bit of allergic to use array indexing for these kind of things. So I prefer using this method.